# How to override 'views-slideshow-pager-fields.tpl.php'?

Tags: paging

I'm taking over one of my co-workers project (i'm new to Drupal...).

I was able to override other view templates such as 'views-view--[my content type].tpl.php', 'views-view-fields--[my content type.tpl.php', but I wasn't able to override 'views-slideshow-pager-fields.tpl.php'.

What naming convention should I use to override the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views Slideshow is a separate module.  [This video](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode42) from MustardseedMedia addresses theming for the module. I have not watched it yet, let us know if it addresses your needs.

Comment: JoeS // That video doesn't explain how to use custom templates...

Comment: Ok, but this one does: http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode49

Comment: JoeS // I appreciate your post, but have you seen the video? It only explains how to work with a custom template. It doesn't talk about 'views-slideshow-pager-fields.tpl.php' template.

Comment: My bad, I misinterpreted the question. I'm just getting into this are of Drupal.  Try copying the same file into your theme folder and edit the new copy.  I suggest doing a simple change first to test it out, but I believe the new one replaces the old.  Let me know how that test goes, since I will be needing something similar soon.